# How to use PostgreSQL varchar column value in IN query

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL database we have a column with varchar value in which values are stored like this [1,2,3,4,5]
I need to check that in a function with In clause.
For example,

```
--Some SQL Query with many joins
AND OtherTable.PhoneNumber NOT IN((myTable.PhoneNumberJson));
```

I tried passing the values in various ways using BLIMIT, RegExReplace and type casting the values but still getting the error.
How to convert the varchar object["1,2,3,4,5"]  list to integer number and use it inside the IN clause.

Comment: Can you post the actual datatypes for the two fields in question?  Is the second an array, and if not, is it formatted literally like that, with the square brackets, double quotes, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use [the `?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to check if a jsonb array contains a given value:

```
AND myTable.PhoneNumberJson ? OtherTable.PhoneNumber
```

Please note that this requires `PhoneNumberJson` to be of `jsonb` datatype. If it's a `json`, then you can cast first:

```
AND myTable.PhoneNumberJson::jsonb ? OtherTable.PhoneNumber
```

Comment: I am sorry for that its my bad, Actually the data type is not json when I changed the query then only I noticed it. It is actually Varchar but the value will be stored like this [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @Samaritan_Learner: if that is the exact format of your string, then I think that you can still cast that to `jsonb`. Please try the second expression in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, there was one more issue that while selecting the number was given as double precision so we need to type cast that as well after doing that it worked. anyway I am marking your answer as correct one because it gives the solution to the original question answered. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am here posting the my expected answer if anybody is searching for how to convert and check not in object for varchar to double precision.

```
and not (myTable.Phone_Number = any  
(array(select 
regexp_split_to_table(replace(replace(other_Table.PhoneNumberJson,'[',''),']',''),','):: 
double precision)));
```